# How to access the node being traversed in the YUI tree

Tags: javascript, yui

I have created a tree data structure using [YUI 3's tree](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tree/).

I can [traverse the tree](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Tree.Node.html#method_traverse) can call a callback function.

I cannot figure out how to access the node being traversed from inside the callback function.

FWIW, I am new to YUI.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node that you're currently traversing will be passed in as the first parameter in the callback function.  For example:

```
var tree = new Y.Tree({
    nodes: [
        /* Add your nodes here */
    ]
});

var root = tree.rootNode;

tree.traverseNode(root, function (node) {
    /* `node` will be the currently traversed node */
    console.log(node);
});
```

Here's an JSBin with working code, if you're still having any trouble getting this to work:

http://jsbin.com/ekilom/2/edit

Hope this helps!